# How to change UIDatePicker to a specific time (in code)

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I need to change the UIDatePicker to a specific dynamically.

My date picker is set to time mode only.
i can set the time with

```
timePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: false)
```

but i cant figure out how to change it to a different time and not to 
current time.

So how do i change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've to change the **time**, you can do it using `NSDateComponents` and set the modified date to your `DatePicker`

```
var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.HourCalendarUnit | NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit, fromDate: NSDate())
components.hour = 5
components.minute = 50
datePicker.setDate(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Please don't ever do this if the `UIDatePicker` is in time only mode. The reason is that, imagine the above code is executed  in New York at 14 March 2021. If the code trying to change the hour = 2. It will be very wrong. Due to Day Light Saving, there is no 2am in 14 March 2021. A correct way is to hard coded a timezone without DST like GMT, so that user can read/ write time only information to DatePicker without the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 and 4:

```
extension UIDatePicker {

   func setDate(from string: String, format: String, animated: Bool = true) {

      let formater = DateFormatter()

      formater.dateFormat = format

      let date = formater.date(from: string) ?? Date()

      setDate(date, animated: animated)
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
datePicker.setDate(from: "1/1/2000 10:10:00", format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Perfect Solution, Thanks @Zombie checked in Swift 4

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents()
components.hour = 5
components.minute = 50
    
timePicker.setDate(calendar.date(from: components)!, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 5):

To set the date pick (time only) to a specific time such as "09:00" I would set the NSDateComponents and picker like this.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.hour = 9
components.minute = 0
timePicker.setDate(calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Useful for setting UIDatePicker when using datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.CountDownTimer

Answer (score 4):

You can customize it by formatting your Date and Time this way:

```
let dateString = "12-11-2015 10:50:00"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

timePicker.setDate(date, animated: false)
```

Comment: i need to set a UIDatePicker not a textfield

Comment: format Date and Time is not the answer for setting date and time for UIDatePicker

Comment: Updated: Divi I see what you try to do and could've made more clear by adding more code to yours. I try to undo vote but couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

you can use it like this

```
timePicker.setDate(NSDate(timeInterval: 60, sinceDate: NSDate()), animated: false)
```

or

```
timePicker.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60), animated: false)
```

it would set date with difference of 1 minute from current date.

Comment: I need to change to a totally different time. i get a time from server in "HH:mm" format and i need to show it in date picker

Answer (score 0):

If u do not want to type multiple lines of code each time when you want Date or Time from string
U can copy below function and use as

```
let DateVar = DateTimeFrmSrgFnc("31/12/1990",FmtSrg: "dd/MM/yyyy")

timePicker.setDate(DateVar, animated: false)

func DateTimeFrmSrgFnc(DateSrgPsgVar: String, FmtSrg FmtSrgPsgVar: String)-> NSDate
{
    // Format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = FmtSrgPsgVar
    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(DateSrgPsgVar)!
}
```