# Swift: Set custom Date(Day only) in DatePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker

I have two date pickers. Let's say `fromDatePicker` and `untilDatePicker`. I set the `untilDatePicker` to current date (ex: 12/06/17) and I want to set the `fromDatePicker` into first date of the current month (ex: 01/06/17) but I don't have any idea to set the `untilDatePicker`.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985483/how-to-change-uidatepicker-to-a-specific-time-in-code) but it's not helped me much.

Comment: I don't understand what you asked.

Comment: sorry i will edit to make more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is swift3 solution and how you set first day of current month in datePicker , if you need to get first of other month just change date variable with some day from that month

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: date as Date)
    let startOfMonth = calendar.date(from: components)
    self.datePicker.setDate(startOfMonth!, animated: true)
```