# Swift : Set minimum/maximum DatePicker to other DatePicker

Tags: swift, datepicker

Based on my previous question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493102/swift-set-custom-dateday-only-in-datepicker) . I have two `datePicker` let say A and B. I want to set maximum of A is B.date and minimum of B is A.date. 
But when i change the B value, the A maximum value still in old B maximum value. I dont have any idea about this.

```
let date = NSDate()
self.datePickerFrom.maximumDate = date as Date
self.datePickerTo.minimumDate = datePickerFrom.date
```

Any sugest and answer will helpfull for me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You set this code in Action of date picker B?

Comment: @Hosny i set this in viewDidLoad. Do i do a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell some function in your view controller that the date pickers have changed.  To do that, declare some @IBAction in your view controller that looks like this:

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker)
{
    print("date has been set to \(sender.date)")
}
```

Then click on your date pickers in your storyboard or XIB file and connect the "Valued Changed" event to this new method.

[image: connect value changed]

Then try running it to see if the `print` line prints in the console.

If it does, you can fill out more of that function.  Perhaps something like this:

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker)
{
     if sender == self.datePickerFrom
     {
          self.datePickerTo.minimumDate = sender.date
     } 
     if sender == self.datePickerTo 
     {
          self.datePickerFrom.maximumDate = sender.date
     }
}
```